# spring, mysql, mybatis test

Tags: mysql, spring, mybatis

I'm testing using Spring, Mysql, MyBatis, but have some problems.
I run my application on tomcat. and my config files are below.

**root-context.xml**

```
    <bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driver}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}​"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}​" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}​" />
</bean>
<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:mybatis-config-base.xml" />
    <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath*:sample/dao/sql/*.xml" />
</bean>

<bean id="sqlSessionTemplate" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

**db.properties**

```
jdbc.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/sample
jdbc.username=player
jdbc.password=qwer1234!!
```

Controller and DAO is simple select.
When I call controller, exception occurs like this.

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user
>   'player?€?'@'localhost' (using password: YES)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:873)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1710)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1226)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2194)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2225)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2024)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:779)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:47)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:389)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:330)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(SimpleDriverDataSource.java:140)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:153)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:119)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
>     ... 57 more

Trace has interesing message.

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'player?€?'@'localhost'(using password: YES)

**?€?**  ====> Where this come from? I checked blank or space.

I have a good working code at same environment.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import org.junit.Test;

public class MySqlTest {

    private final String DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test";
    private final String USER ="player";
    private final String PW = "qwer1234!!";

    @Test
    public void test() {
        try{
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PW); 
        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("select * from sample");
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        System.out.println(rs);
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

any hint?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found it myself.
it was a file encoding issue.